# Changing an abstract class to non abstract with AspectJ?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

As far as I know I can use AspectJ to replace an abstract method for a concrete implementation.

Is it also possible to use AspectJ (or another AOP language) to change the definition of a class from being abstract to non-abstract ? (after providing a concrete implementation for all the abstract methods in the abstract class using inter-type declarations).

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The simpler way is to make the class non-abstract and provide default "do nothing" implementations for all methods

Comment: hi @Bohemian. What happens is that it is a recurrent case, and I did not want to ask the users of my library to always write do nothing implementations. Besides, if there are no abstract methods I would have to define a mechanism for recognizing the methods the library should instrument (e.g., with annotations). From the user of my library point of view it is easier and faster if they just declare the methods as abstract instead of adding annotations and do nothing implementations. Of course, it is more work for the library implementor, but I would like to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I recommend this:

- make you'd class non-absteact (remove the absteact keyword)
- provide default implementations that throw a runtime exception

This will force the users of your library to provide impls for the "abstact" methods, but allow your class to be concrete.

This pattern is already in use in the JDK.

Comment: Hi @Bohemian. I think there is a misunderstanding (I think I did not explained it right in my last comment, sorry). I need to instrument certain classes of the user (they do not inherit from a class in my library). I could recognize the methods to instrument as all of them that are abstract. If the class is not abstract anymore and the "abstract" methods provide default implementations, I would have to ask the programmer to annotate the methods that my library should instrument. I am looking for a mechanism that could free the users of my library from that.